# Sencha Touch: Cmd-built app not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am working with ST2.3.1 and Cmd 4. My app builds and runs fine on my desktop browser but does not launch on a browser on my mobile device. The loading dots with blue background shows up and then just hangs.

I tried this with a testing build on an iPhone 4S with Safari and Chrome, with similar results. So I pulled up the app in Safari, and opened Safari Web Inspector to see what's going on, and I cannot see anything unusual in the index.html. I have taken a screenshot and attached it below. The fact that the loading dots show up and the index.html loads means that I dont have a problem accessing the webserver.

Any ideas why the app may not be launching? Should I expect a testing build from cmd to work just the same way on a mobile browser as on a desktop, or does that require additional setup/configuration? My build settings are otherwise unchanged and use default settings mostly. Could this be a Mac OS X firewall problem? It's running on default factory settings.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: It sounds like a cross-browser request problem: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`